# Application of Weierstrass' theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Consider $f \in C^1[0,1]$ where $C^1[0,1]$ is the space of functions of class $C^1$ on $[0,1]$ furnished with the norm $\|f\| = \|f \|_\infty + \| f' \|_\infty$. Prove that for $\epsilon > 0$, there is a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $\|f - p\|< \epsilon.$

So I thought that since $f'$ is continuous there is a polynomial $q(x)$ such that $\| f' - q \|_\infty < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ by Weierstrass's theorem.

Now by fundamental theorem of calculus, $$f(x) = f(a) + \int_{a}^{x} f'(t) dt$$

$$f(x) - \int_{a}^{x} q(t) dt= f(a) + \int_{a}^{x} f'(t) - q(t) dt \leq f(a) + \frac{\epsilon}{2}(x - a).$$

I know that $p(x) = \int_{a}^{x} q(t) dt$ by my own intuition, but how do I rigorous prove this (because the degree of $q$ will be one higher after integration)?  Also how do I get rid of the $\frac{\epsilon}{2}x$ and $f(a)$ factor?

Answer (score 3):

Let $q$ be a polynomial such that $\|f'-q\|_{\infty} \leq \varepsilon/2$ and set

$$p(x) := f(0) + \int_0^x q(y) \, dy.$$

Obviously, $p$ is a polynomial and $p' =q$. Moreover, by the fundamental theorem of calculus

$$\begin{align*} |f(x)-p(x)| &= \left| \left(f(0)+ \int_0^x f'(y) \, dy \right)- \left( f(0)+ \int_0^x q(y) \, dy  \right) \right| \\ &= \left| \int_0^x (f'(y)-q(y)) \, dy \right| \\ &\leq \int_0^x |f'(y)-q(y)| \, dy \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \cdot x \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \end{align*}$$

for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Why are you allowed to set $p(x) := f(0) + \int_{0}^{x}q(y) dy$? That's what I am mainly confused with.

Comment: @Hawk Well, the integral $\int_0^x q(y) \, dy$ is well-defined (it is an integral over a polynomial) - so why should it be *not* allowed to define $p$ this way?